# Поиск острова дат

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, function-overloading, sql-server-2017

Sql server 2017.
Есть таблица с историчностью(Temporal tables).
Стоит задача получить историю, но не по всем полям, а по определенным. Следующий запрос:

```
SELECT cd.id,
                        cd.fn_factory_number,
                        cd.outlet_id,
                        cd.valid_from,
                        cd.valid_to
              FROM dbo.cashdesk_data
                  FOR SYSTEM_TIME all AS cd
              WHERE cd.id = 1
              ORDER BY cd.valid_to
```

выдает

[image: результат запроса]

Такой результат истории выдает, потому что были изменены другие поля этой таблицы, которые для данной задачи не имеют значения.
По факту задача стоит определить максимальную и минимальную дату в окне id, fn_factory_number, outlet_id, но только в окне, которое не было прервано другим окном.
Если показать наглядно на скриншоте, то каждое окно в рамках которого мне нужно вычислить минимальную и максимальную дату, отмечены отдельными цветами.
[image: Какие окна я хочу получить]

Как это сделать без построчного пребора и дополнительных вычислений представить не могу.
По хорошему нужно вычислить какое то подобие ранга, что бы было как на скриншоте, что бы сгруппировать по этому полю и получить min max дат.

[image: Вычисляемый столбец, который хотелось бы получить]

Но как это сделать без перебора строк в курсоре, хотелось как нибудь решить этот вопрос в рамках множеств. Но кидайте любые варинты, может меня озарит или может будет какой то, который мне понравится.
Еще на ум приходит рекурсивная cto, но чет придумать не могу.

Comment: Т.е. по факту требуемое окно - это идущие подряд одинаковые outlet_id для тех же id, fn_factory_number в порядке valid_to ? Или надо что бы глобально по порядку valid_to изменение любого из 3х полей переключало окно ?

Comment: Получается 2 вариант.
Да, что бы изменение fn_factory_number или outlet_id переключало окно на следующие, но если далее встретятся такие же  fn_factory_number или outlet_id как и в первом окне, они считались новым окном.
По факту на те окна, которые мне нужны, я разбил в третьем скриншоте с помощью paint и колонке rn.

Comment: Коллеги, есть ли более емкое описание того что я здесь хотел сделать? Темпоральные таблицы набирают обороты, а простейшая задача в них решается сложно, что бы было проще найти людям, может модераторы изменят вопрос

Comment: Что значит "более емкое" ? И кстати, что с приведенными ответами, они должны решать вашу задачу. Если не решают, то напишите что с ними не так и приведите таблицу в текстовом виде, что бы можно было прямо на ней написать контрольный пример (например на sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Публикую своё решение. Оконные функции используются для определения границы "островов".

```sql
SELECT 
     id
    ,fn_factory_number
    ,outlet_id
    ,ISNULL(LAG(next_window_valid_from) OVER (ORDER BY row), min_valid_to) AS valid_from
    ,valid_to
FROM (
    SELECT
         id
        ,fn_factory_number
        ,outlet_id
        ,valid_to
        ,min_valid_to
        ,row
        ,IIF(LEAD(row_part) OVER (ORDER BY row) - row_part = 1, 0, 1) AS window_end
        ,LEAD(valid_from) OVER (ORDER BY row) AS next_window_valid_from
    FROM (
        SELECT
             id
            ,fn_factory_number
            ,outlet_id
            ,valid_from
            ,valid_to
            ,MIN(valid_from) OVER (ORDER BY valid_to) AS min_valid_to
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY valid_to) AS row
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, fn_factory_number, outlet_id ORDER BY valid_to) AS row_part
        FROM dbo.cashdesk_data
        FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
        WHERE id = 1
    ) parts
) windows
WHERE window_end = 1
ORDER BY row;
```

Comment: Да, это именно то что я искал. Работает!

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку, ввиду отсутствия примера данных в виде текста и вопросе, должно быть что то в этом роде:

```
select *, sum(grp) over(order by dt) grp
  from (
    select *,
           case when
              coalesce(lag(fn_factory_number) over(order by cd.valid_to), fn_factory_number) = fn_factory_number and
              coalesce(lag(outlet_id) over(order by cd.valid_to), outlet_id) = outlet_id
           then 0 else 1 end grp
      from cashdesk_data ...
) x
```

Функция `lag()` дает значение колонки из предыдущей строки в указанном порядке сортировки. Сравниваем значения c текущим, если отличается выставляем 1. Во внешнем запросе считаем сумму этих 1 оконной функцией в указанном порядке сортировки. Таким образом формируется номер группы к которой следует относить строку. Остается сгруппировать под данному полю (`grp`) и вычислить необходимые минимумы/максимумы